# Importing directly from SRC folder does not work in WITE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, npx

I had some issues with npx i so I moved my project into a new folder where I created the react app using Vite.

All I did was to replace the src folder into the vite app, but now I get a tone of errors of type "Failed to resolve import". This is because in the app built with npx I had a `jsconfig.jsos` file with the base URL pointing at the src folder and all my imports ar starting with `components/` `hooks/` etc.

I have followed a article to see how I can import directly from the src in the vite and the article made me change my vite-config.js file to this

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: '/src',
    },
  },
});
```

and create a `jsconfig.json` file and add this to the file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to be able to import directly from the src when using vite? Fixing the errors by hand would take a really long time